# Split String Date Text from TextView gets empty Array: Error -> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=2

Tags: java, android

I try to edit a String input from a TextView via String.split().

The input is a String in Format dd.mm.yyyy and I want to transform it to yyyy-mm-dd
I got the input from an intent, set it to the TextView. Later, without changing anything, I read the Text from the TextView and try to split it.

```
String date = intent.getStringExtra("date");
mDisplayDate.setText(date);
.
.
.
String userDate = mDisplayDate.getText().toString();
Log.i("TAG","userDate = "+ userDate);
String[] separated = userDate.split(".");
Log.i("TAG","Array = "+ Arrays.toString(separated));
newDate = separated[2] + "-" + separated[1] + "-" + separated[0];
```

Log: userDate = 30.06.2020

Log: Array = [] -> so it is a empty Array... but why?

If I seperate by e.g. a number it works... I am lost...

Comment: Make sure the character is really the one you think. It could be any unicode point and you wouldn't know. Otherwise you can always just split by non-digit regex: `[^0-9]`

Comment: I got the hint that I have to seperate it with "\\." because of the speziall meaning of ".". I searched for a log time, but couldnt find anything. I guess I have to improve my search skills. Thanks @Andreas

Comment: For me, it is top search result when searching for [`java split period`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+split+period) using Google.